# Force to separate magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, home-experiment

I need to know how much force it takes to separate two magnets or a magnet from a piece of metal.

I've bought a spring scale that measures max 50 grams, so it's very accurate.

Now what if I attach the scale to the magnet and I pull it horizontally just enough to separate the magnets and the meter reads 10 grams, does it then mean it took 0.001 Newton to separate the magnets? And can I use that to convert it into watt-hours to have a mechanism separate the magnet with that amount of watt-hours?

Comment: More on force between two magnets: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+force+two+magnets